# Force close an incompatible workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am manipulating by code a large number of Excel files. I go through them automatically: open one file, do some operations and then close it.

For some files, at the place of

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

an error pops-un, which stops my automation:

[image]

Does anyone know how to force-close such a workbook (and other workbooks) and do not let it stop my automation?

**Edit 1:** I try to look into the VBA code of `ThisWorkbook`, but **they are protected by a password**. I think this is their common point.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and then after closing turning it back on ?

Comment: I did... `DisplayAlerts` is `False` throughout the whole program...

Comment: See this maybe you can find solution there http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629554-compile-error-hidden-module-thisworkbook.html

Comment: Did you look at the "ThisWorkbook" module of the workbook in question, to see what code is contained there?

By the way - I think DisplayAlerts only suppresses things like unsaved warnings. If there is an error within the VBA itself, then DisplayAlerts won't help you.

Comment: Are you referencing `ThisWorkbook` or are you using a variable to target each book?

Comment: If I'm assuming right, the code in the workbook opened is code-protected, and the code that's giving the error should be on an event procedure. Have you tried: EnableEvents=False : ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False : EnableEvents=True

Comment: Manipulating `EnableEvents` does not help...